# Common styles for elements and modifiers

Tags: sass, bem

if I have:

```
.control-button {
  border: 1px solid red;

  &--primary {
    color: blue;
  }
  &--secondary {
    color: white;
  }
}
```

how do I make sure that border gets set in both button classes? As it is right now it generates following css:

```
.control-button {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.control-button--primary {
  color: blue;
}
.control-button--secondary {
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is possible using string interpolation:

```
.control-button {
  $c: &;              // store classname as a var

  border: 1px solid red;

  &--primary {
    @extend #{$c};

    color: blue;
  }
  &--secondary {
    @extend #{$c};

    color: white;
  }
}
```

That generates following css:

```
.control-button, .control-button--primary, .control-button--secondary {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.control-button--primary {
  color: blue;
}
.control-button--secondary {
  color: white;
}
```

It works, yet **this probably, arguably a stupid way**. Makes things a bit cryptic. But it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You apply both classes to the element:

`<button class="control-button control-button--primary">Primary button</button>
<button class="control-button control-button--secondary">Secondary button</button>`

The block class defines any shared styling and modifier classes can be used to override or extend it.

Comment: Yeah, but let's say I can't or I don't want to. How do I do that in scss, elegantly? There's a way to get a common mixin, but that again repeats things

Comment: Yeah you could create a mixin or use `@extend` to share a bunch of common properties across CSS classes, but then you're not really using BEM properly. The approach above is pretty powerful because you can obviously combine any number of modifiers.

Comment: Out of interest, why can't you or won't you?

Comment: well, a) I have academic curiosity if that's somehow doable b) my colleague is working on the behavior and markup part of the page, I have to deal with styles, we're working in parallel, I can't change the markup, I have basic scaffolding of it

Comment: I think if you want to get the best out of BEM, or possibly other component based CSS methodologies, you're going to need more control over the CSS classes which are added to the markup. I'd argue it's part of your remit as the owner of the styling.